# Is there a way to create a marquee text in a Wear OS tile?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, wear-os

I am using Jetpack Compose for Wear OS and I am creating a tile that I would like to display some marquee text on - like a news ticker.
Is there a way to do this?

I tried creating a function like this:

```
@ExperimentalFoundationApi
private fun marqueeText(context: Context, text: String): LayoutElementBuilders.LayoutElement =
    LayoutElementBuilders.Column.Builder()
        .setWidth(DimensionBuilders.DpProp.Builder().setValue(100f).build())
        .setModifiers(ModifiersBuilders.Modifiers.Builder()
            .apply { Modifier.basicMarquee(
                iterations = Int.MAX_VALUE,
                animationMode = MarqueeAnimationMode.Immediately,
                delayMillis = 0,
                initialDelayMillis = 0,
                spacing = MarqueeSpacing.fractionOfContainer(0.9f),
                velocity = 0.dp
            ) }
            .build())
        .addContent(Text.Builder(context, text)
            .setTypography(Typography.TYPOGRAPHY_CAPTION2)
            .build()
        )
        .build()
```

But it does not work. The text is displayed but is does not scroll.

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to do so... The "official" tiles from samsung and google does not have such feature... And tiles also have a limit on how many times you can request a update without user interaction.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://devcodef1.com/news/1093100/marquee-text-in-wear-os

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment by @dect, the behavior you are looking for is (at least currently) not supported.

Tiles are not a suitable surface for any type of custom animations. They were designed to be updated in minute intervals, most likely to minimize the impact on battery life. You *can* force a higher refresh rate, but anything below ~5 seconds tend to get unpredictable. Trust me I've tried...

The best (and maybe only?) way to get close to real-time content updates in a Tile is using a [dynamic expression](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/tiles/dynamic).

Combined with [content update animations](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/tiles/animations), this gives you a way show fresh data in an aesthetically pleasing way, without wasting precious power.

Unfortunately, I can't think of a way to combine the two to achieve the ticker effect you're looking for. Hopefully the links above can at least inspire you to come up with an alternative acceptable solution.